# Proving second linearity property

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that 
$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y), \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$.
Show that $f(r)=rf(1),\forall r \in \mathbb Q$ then find an expression of $f$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: First show that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, 
$$f(n) = nf(1)$$
then continue with any *integer* and also show that
$$f\big( \tfrac{1}{q} \big) = \tfrac{1}{q} f(1)$$
which is the same as 
$$q f\big( \tfrac{1}{q} \big) = f(1)$$
for every nonzero integer $q$.

Comment: Great ! I just needed the idea, thank you for the help :)

Comment: Your welcome! ..